# Using nested properties in $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's assume I have a Person object. Each Person has *n* number of houses and each house has *m* number of rooms in it. In each room there is a special item id and I also have a collection of these items. So my Person object looks kinda like this:

```
person: {
    name: "Fictional Name",
    houses: [
        {
            rooms: [
                {
                    itemId : "q23434c23"
                },{
                    itemId : "q34c356b5"
                },{...}
            ]
        },{...}
    ]
}
```

Now when i aggregate my *person* collection i try to `$lookup` all these `itemId`'s inside of it and store them as a variable. The problem is I don't know how to look them up. I tried running code below, but it works only for the first House:

```
db.persons.aggregate([
    {
       $lookup: {
           from: "items",
           localField: "houses.rooms.itemId",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "myItems"
       }
    },{
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            myItems: "$myItems"
        }
    }
])
```

Edit: *item* looks kinda like this:

```
item: {
    _id: "q23434c23",
    type: "PLASTIC",
    description: "basic description"
}
```

Comment: Where is your items collection?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I don't understand the question. *items* collection is in the same database as my *person* collection.

Comment: Please show some sample collection from the `items` collection as well

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet ok sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.persons.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$houses" }
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "items",
    "localField": "houses.rooms.itemId",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "houses.rooms"
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "houses": { "$push": "$houses" }
    "name": { "$first": "$name" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: But what if I want to include `type` and `description` fileds in `"houses"`?

Comment: It will better if you will ask a new question with proper details. I will surely help you